# Width of my textarea and input field are not thesame

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS. I want to create a form with flexbox and for some reason width of my input fields and text area are not the same. Is there something missing on my code? TIA!

Here is my CSS code for my textarea and input field. For more details check [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/iregret/pen/ZEMmZvq)

```
.flex-outer label {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.flex-outer input {
    flex: 2;
}

input, textarea {
    width: 200px;
}

label[for="message"] {
    align-self: center;
  }
```

Comment: Please make sure you include a [mre] in the question itself, in this case, it looks like the `.flex-outer input` rule is causing the problem (which we can't see without visiting the codepen link)

Comment: Re edit: Please include a [mcve]. We can't tell how your CSS interacts with the HTML you haven't included. See also [stack snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you applied `flex: 2;` just for input, add `textarea` too and your problem will be solved:

```css
.flex-outer input,
textarea {
  flex: 2;
}
```